# Два словаря, Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеются два словаря, необходимо исключить один словарь из другого. Как это сделать наибыстрейшим способом? Изначально задача стояла по-другому. Имеется набор объектов, и по их id создается запрос к базе данных (для этого всего используется ORM). Так же имеется словарь строк. Каждый объект имеет строковое представления (к примеру поле name). Задача состоит в том, что бы исключить все объекты, чьи имена имеются в словаре. Я делал запрос к БД, получал словарь со строковым представлением.

```
dict1 = SomeObject.objects.filter(nodes__id__in=[o.id for o in obj]).distinct()
dict2 = inputStringDict

# Далее необходимо исключить из словаря dict1 словарь dict2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте проделывал бы операции с неизвестным количеством данных (а из базы может прийти, например, миллион строк) до победного использовал ORM, который в свою очередь интерпретируется в SQL.

```
dict2 = inputStringDict
dict1 = (SomeObject.objects.filter(nodes__id__in=[o.id for o in obj])
                           .distinct()
                           .exclude(some_param__in=dict2.keys()))
```

А следующий код превысит лимиты памяти:

```
set(dict2) - set(dict1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Вообще говоря, обычно делают одним из этих двух способов:

```
diff = set(dict2)-set(dict1)
```

Или так:

```
diff = [ k for k in dict2 if k not in dict1 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

### Разность двух словарей

[image: A-B Venn diagram]
<sub>(источник: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/f/fd/Venn_A_setminus_B.svg/1200px-Venn_A_setminus_B.svg.png))</sub>

Чтобы найти все ключи, из `A` словаря, которых нет в `B` словаре на Питоне 3:

```
>>> A, B = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'd': 5}
>>> A.keys() - B.keys()  
{'b', 'c'}
```

В Питоне 2, в этом случае необходимо использовать `viewkeys()` вместо `keys()`. Дополнительная память нужна только под результат—[dictview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) не создаёт копию.

Чтобы вернуть разницу как словарь:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in A.items() if k not in B}
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Можно по месту удалить элементы из `A`, не создавая новый словарь:

```
>>> for k in B:
...     if k in A:
...         del A[k]
>>> A
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Какой из вариантов более предпочтителен зависит от конкретной задачи: какой результат хочется получить, от размера данных, размера результата, размера начального пересечения между словарями. Profiler подскажет какой из вариантов является самым быстрым с вашими входными данными на вашем железе, используя ваши версии ПО.

Связанный вопрос: [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044)

#### Данные ещё не загружены из базы данных

Для наилучшего быстродействия, следует рассмотреть вариант с фильтрацией данных на стороне базы данных, до того как они как объекты Питона загружены, например, [как показано в ответе @MyNameIss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/6253/23044).

<sub>ответ про словари для людей, которые как и я пришли из поисковика в поисках ответа об операциях над словарями</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Надо чуть точнее определить, что за задача стоит.
Если задача стоит как исключить из первого словаря элементы, чьи ключи встречаются в dict2.keys(), то сойдёт следующий код:

```
dict([(k, v) for k, v in dict1.iteritems() if k not in dict2])
```

Немного странным кажется то, что dict2, используется, по сути, как множество своих ключей, а не как словарь. Быть может, множество исключаемых объектов подошло бы лучше? Код, приведённый выше, от этого не изменится.
Если же нужно получить множество ключей первого словаря, которых нет во втором, то ответ уже приводился:

```
set(dict2) - set(dict1)
```