# Разница списков в Python

Tags: python, список

Имеется три списка: `список1`, `список2` и `список3`.

Известно, что `список1 > список2` (по количеству элементов), а `список3` - пустой.

Также известно, что первые элементы `список1` и `список2` одинаковые (например, `список1 = [Вася, Петя, Маша, Саша]`, а `список2 = [Вася, Петя]`).

Задача: заполнить `список3` разностью первого и второго списков, т.е. на приведённом примере `список3 = [Маша, Саша]`.

Comment: связанный вопрос, но про разность словарей:  [Два словаря, Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560/23044)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Навскидку (т.к. set, элементы на выходе будут уникальными, т.е. без повторений) + не важно какие индексы у элементов, которые есть в обоих списках:

```
list1 = [u'Вася', u'Петя', u'Маша', u'Саша']   
list2 = [u'Вася', u'Петя'] 
list3=list(set(list1)-set(list2))  
print list3  
[u'Маша', u'Саша']
```

Comment: большое спасибо :) то, что доктор прописал :)

Answer (score 5):

Используйте [Set](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html). Вот пример из документации.

```
>>> from sets import Set
>>> engineers = Set(['John', 'Jane', 'Jack', 'Janice'])
>>> programmers = Set(['Jack', 'Sam', 'Susan', 'Janice'])
>>> managers = Set(['Jane', 'Jack', 'Susan', 'Zack'])
>>> employees = engineers | programmers | managers           # union
>>> engineering_management = engineers & managers            # intersection
>>> fulltime_management = managers - engineers - programmers # difference
```

difference - это и будет разница

**UPD:**
Опередили меня. :-)

Answer (score 5):

> - Заведомо известно, что список 1 > список2
> - Также известно, что первые элементы список1 и список2 одинаковые

Если выполнение этих условий гарантируется, то самым простым и самым быстрым будет решение:

```
list3 = list1[len(list2):]
```

Comment: гарантируется только: `list1[:k] == list2[:k]`. Не гарантируется, что `k == len(list2)` и не сказано, что больше нет одинаковых элементов, то есть возможно: `list2[j] in list1` для какого-нибудь `j > k`. Условия похоже просто дымовую завесу создают, а решение такое же как для любых двух списков, чтобы найти их разность (list1-list2): `list3[:] = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]`, где `list2` можно на `set(list2)` заменить для больших `list2` (чтобы избежать `O(n**2)` время). Или `list3[:] = set(list1).difference(list2)`, если только уникальные элементы без учёта порядка интересуют.

Answer (score 4):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3',]
list2 = ['1', '3',]
for item in list2:
    if item in list1:
        list1.remove(item)
#Искомый - list1
```

Я правильно понял ваш вопрос? Тут только вычёркивание элементов второго списка из первого.

Comment: не совсем правильно вы меня поняли, но за ответ спасибо, может быть и пригодится :)

Comment: Да ничего, я на скорую руку набросал что-то непонятное ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> lst1 = ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Маша', 'Саша']
>>> lst2 = ['Вася', 'Петя']
>>> lst3 = [i for i in lst1 if i not in lst2]
>>> lst3
['Маша', 'Саша']
>>>
```

а множества не гарантируют сохранение порядка элементов

может получиться

```
['Саша', 'Маша']
```

Answer (score 4):

Для этого в python есть специальный ТД "множество" - set. С ним все делается просто и легко.

```
list1 = ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Маша', 'Саша']
list2 = ['Вася', 'Петя']

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
list3 = list( set1.difference(set2) )
```