# Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?

Tags: python, типы-данных, language-lawyer

Почему списки, кортежи, множества можно, а словари - нельзя?

Если вам не нравится `+`, можно же было сделать fluent interface - чтобы `dict.update()` возвращал self.

Самое лучшее, что я нашел - `dict(dict1, key1=value1)`.

Пример использования:

```
base_config = {'key1': 'val1'}

func1(base_config + {'key2': 'val2'})
func2(base_config + {'key3': 'val3'})
```

Comment: В чём проблема с `func1(base_config, key2='val2')`?

Comment: В том, что func принимает dict? Вы кое-что путаете.

Comment: 1. Изменить `func()`, чтобы `**kwargs` принимала 2. Или явно `dict()` создавать: `func1(dict(base_config, key2='val2'))
`

Comment: @jfs а если функция не ваша?

Comment: обратите внимание на пункт 2 в моем предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: @jfs Этот пример я до вас запостил

Comment: Если Вы нашли ответ на вопрос, то добавьте его в виде *ответа*. Если решение не устраивает, то следует явно указать в чём проблема с ним.

Comment: @jfs во-первых, он мне не нравится, во-вторых, ключи не могут начинаться с цифр.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: @SmitJohnth, я откатил вашу правку, т.к. это не нужно в вопросе. Про данную функциональность смотрите в начале ответа от jfs к вашему вопросу.

Comment: ахаха, я ржу. Меня в коментах убеждали что это нинужно, а тут взяли и добавили это в питон, один к одному, только | вместо +. Комментаторы которые писали что я дурак и ничего не понимаю, не хотите поменять своё мнение? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583116/why-is-arithmetic-not-supported-for-dict-usupported-operand-types-for-dic

Answer (score 36):

*Update*: В Python 3.9 реализовано [PEP 584 -- Add Union Operators To dict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/):

```
>>> {0: 'a', 1: 'b'} | {False: 'A', 2: 'C'}
{0: 'A', 1: 'b', 2: 'C'}
```

объединение словарей с помощью `|` (union) операции: [более левые  ключи (как у `|` операции для set)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007408/4279) выигрывают и более правые (поздние) значения выигрывают (как `dict_add_keep_last()` ниже).

Есть также и по месту операция (изменяет словарь) и можно передавать не только словари:

```
>>> d = {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}
>>> d |= [(False, 'A'), (2, 'C')]
>>> d
{0: 'A', 1: 'b', 2: 'C'}
```

---

<sup>Cтарый ответ:</sup>

Потому что не ясно какую операцию `+` должен реализовывать для словарей. И предпочтительные для каждого конкретного случая варианты легко реализовать.

Из ["The Zen of Python" (`import this`)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
```

[BDFL (2009)](http://web.archive.org/web/20180310222202/http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/3505):

> Because there so many different ways to think about this, it's better
>   not to guess and force the user to be explicit.

Guido (2019): [Why operators are useful](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2019/03/why-operators-are-useful.html).

Например (псевдо-код):

```
result = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} + {'a': 3, 'c': 0}
```

Возможны разные ответы:

- сохранять только последние значения ([PEP-0584 поведение](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/))

  ```
  result = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
  ```

  можно реализовать так:

  ```
  def dict_add_keep_last(a, b): # aka merged() or updated()
      d = a.copy()
      d.update(b)
      return d
  ```

  В специальных случаях, когда ключи являются строками можно без функции обойтись (в Питоне 2 (CPython) также разрешены произвольные ключи), [пример](http://ideone.com/UkOlPk):

  ```
  result = dict(a, **b) # результат тот же
  ```

  [Guido не любит такую конструкцию](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html).

  Или для произвольных словарей в Питоне 3.5 ([PEP 0448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)):

  ```
  result = {**a, **b}
  ```

  см. [Adding dictionaries together, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6005066/4279) (следуй по ссылкам по цепочке, есть хорошие ответы у каждого вопроса).
- сохранять первые значения (возможно ближе к тому как `|` операция реализована у `set()`):

  ```
  result = {**b, **a} # Python 3.5, or else swap a, b: dict_add_keep_last(b, a)
  ```
- суммировать значения как `collections.Counter` (Multiset semantics):

  ```
  >>> from collections import Counter
  >>> Counter(a) + Counter(b)
  Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2})
  ```

  Ключи с нулевыми (и отрицательными) значениями (`'c'`) не сохраняются.
- как-то по-другому комбинировать, чтобы не терять информацию, например, [sum_dict()](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/3502) или:

  ```
  result = {'a': [1, 3], 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
  ```

  Use-case: [повторяющиеся ключи в json объекте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828652/4279)
- завершаться с ошибкой в случае ключей-дубликатов, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14902564/4279).

Никакой из представленных вариантов не является более очевидным (точнее *разные* люди могут считать *разные* варианты более очевидными). Более того, каждый из этих вариантов имеет право на существование и они *не всегда взаимозаменяемы*. Различные варианты сложения словарей используются не очень часто, поэтому важно, чтобы в каждом случае *явно* было указано, какой тип операции используется и не нужно было *гадать* (ошибки менее вероятны).

Идея обсуждалась в списке рассылки (python-ideas) неоднократно:

- ["Adding "+" and "+=" operators to dict" (2015)](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/31750)
- ["adding dictionaries" (2014)](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/28425)
- ["dict '+' operator and slicing support for pop" (2009)](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/3498)

Мелкие замечания (не имеют отношения к "почему", но полезны для темы "сложить два словаря"):

- тип возвращаемого значения для `a + b` выражения, как обычно, не очевиден и может зависеть от типа `a` и `b` например, выражение `a += b`, может "поменять" тип `a`:

  ```
  >>> from decimal import Decimal
  >>> a = 1
  >>> a += Decimal(2)
  >>> a
  Decimal('3')
  ```
- также, в случае нескольких словарей, `+` синтаксис поощряет неэффективный (память, время исполнения) код для больших словарей, например, `a += b + c + d + ..` (`O(N*k**2)`) можно записать более эффективно как (`O(N*k)`):

  ```
  for it in [b, c, d, ..]:
      a.update(it)
  ```
- иногда (например, для больших словарей, в которых только некоторые ключи являются интересными) можно "лениво" (`O(k)`) слить словари, используя `ChainMap`:

  ```
  try: 
      from collections import ChainMap
  except ImportError: # Python 2
      from ConfigParser import _Chainmap as ChainMap
  ```

  [`pylookup = ChainMap(locals(), globals(), vars(builtins))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-examples-and-recipes)

---

> Если вам не нравится +, можно же было сделать fluent interface - чтобы
>   dict.update() возвращал self.

Потому что в Питоне методы, которые изменяют объект, обычно возвращают `None`, типичный пример: `some_list.sort()` vs. `sorted(some_list)`. Питон следует принципу [Command–query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Answer (score 6):

Потому что в словаре есть ключи, которые могут совпадать в двух разных словарях.

Comment: Хочешь сказать, что сложение выйдет некомутативным? Но для списков оно такое же.

Comment: Возникает неоднозначность при сложении значений с одинаковыми ключами.

Comment: Например, в `a+b` заменить значения `a` значениями  `b`

Comment: А кто то другой захочет наоборот ;-) Когда неоднозначность разработчики библиотек умывают руки и предоставляют такую возможность реализовать тем кому это нужно.

Comment: А как со списками? А вдруг там кто-то захочет наоборот :) Почему нельзя сделать, чтобы dict.update возвращало self? `func(dict1.update(dict2))`

Comment: Возможно, проблема так же в том, что однаковый Key в разных словарях может соотвествовать разным типам данных в Value.

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Со списками неоднозначности нету, у кого то могут возникнуть сомнения что результатом [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6] будет что то другое чем [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]? А тем кому нужно наоборот допишут reverse.

Comment: @cpp_user см комент с update

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from <source>, overwriting existing keys. Функция явно не универсальная.

Comment: @cpp_user что значит не универсальная? Не может сложить словарь с бубликом?

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Значит то что имеет ограничения о которых нужно знать.

Comment: @cpp_user "что значит не универсальная?" Озвучьте

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Ответил же выше.

Comment: @cpp_user где ответ?

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Не универсальная это значит то что она имеет ограничения о которых нужно знать. - cpp_user 1 час назад

Comment: @cpp_user какие, блин? Назовите их уже.

Comment: @Smit Johnth: overwriting existing keys.- этого мало для ограничений?

Comment: Это **ограничение**? Блин, а dict.update делает то же, давайте и его запретим...

Comment: @Smit Johnth: Вам в другом ответе выше уже подробно расписали что такое поведение не всех устраивает, а раз кого то не устраивает то это для него естественно является серьезным ограничением и его нельзя применять по умолчанию для всех через operator +.

Comment: @cpp_user написал в вопрос про update. А меня не устраивает, что список нельзя складывать с кортежем, что теперь?

Comment: @Smit Johnth: dict.update это по сути функция хелпер которая подойдет многим но не всем, а operator + нужен всем. Видишь разницу в применении? А так как такой универсальной функции не существует то и operator + не определен.

Comment: @cpp_user да мне пофиг, сделайте хоть через update, только чтобы без создания промежуточных переменных

Answer (score 2):

Операция сложения для словарей в Python не определена.

При острой необходимости имитировать такое поведение:

```
import itertools
base_config = {'key1': 'val1'}

func1(dict(itertools.chain(base_config.iteritems(), {'key2': 'val2'}.iteritems())))
func2(dict(itertools.chain(base_config.iteritems(), {'key3': 'val3'}.iteritems())))
```

При одинаковых ключах приоритет отдается последнему вхождению.

Для Python3 `.iteritems(...)` заменить на `.items(...)`

Comment: не нужно такие ужасы изобретать. Посмотрите на [различные решения, представленные в ссылках в моём ответе: разные по читаемости, производительности, с ограничениями на ключи и т.д.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431781/23044), особенно [пройдите по цепочке вопросов, чтобы посмотреть на разные решения](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6005066/4279)