# Как добавить новые значения из списка в словарь: "значение -> количество его повторений"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеем словарь:  `items = {'coin': 43, 'apple': 5}`
Как добавить сюда новые значения из списка:
`new = ['coin', 'coin', 'apple', 'axe', 'sword']`?

Comment: Вы знаете, как вообще новые значения в словарь добавлять? А как значения из списка получать? С чем именно затруднения?

Comment: Если значения из списка станут ключами в словаре, то что станет значениями? Как обрабатывать дублирующиеся элементы списка (как `coin`)?

Comment: Знаю, нужно написать функцию dict(x, y) по добавлению значений из списка в словарь  , где x - это словарь, а y - это список

Comment: Собственно в этом и дело, как сложить значения дублирующихся элементов и добавить новые элементы с новыми значениями

Comment: связанный вопрос: [сложить два словаря](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044)

Answer (score 1):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) вернет словарь с подсчитанными элементами списка

```
items = {'coin': 43, 'apple': 5}
new = ['coin', 'coin', 'apple', 'axe', 'sword']

from collections import Counter
def add_to_dict(x: dict, y: list):
    for k, v in Counter(y).items():
        x[k] = x.get(k, 0) + v
add_to_dict(items, new)
print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
new = ['coin', 'coin', 'apple', 'axe', 'sword']
items = {'coin': 43, 'apple': 5}

for x in new:
    if x in items:
        items[x] += 1
    else:
        items[x] = 0

print(items)
```

## Result:

```
#{'sword': 0, 'coin': 45, 'apple': 6, 'axe': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить новые предметы, обновив количество старых, если необходимо:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(items) + Counter(new)
Counter({'coin': 45, 'apple': 6, 'axe': 1, 'sword': 1})
```

Видно что  удобно использовать Counter как множество (набор) элементов, которые могут повторяться—[мультимножество (multiset)](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE). Counter также можно как обычный словарь использовать, поэтому результат можно оставить как есть, не преобразовывая в dict—учитывая задачу, наоборот следовало бы изначально Counter вместо dict использовать.