# как в существующий словарь добавить новые ключи со значением?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть словарь с значениями, необходимо добавить в него новые элементы

`D['b']['c']['d'] = [2], [3], [4]` - не работает

Comment: для ясности, приведите пример ввода/вывода.  Вы хотите: `for  key, value in zip('bcd', [2, 3, 4]): D[key] = value`? (плоская структура) или хотите вложенную структуру на лету создать? [`reduce(lambda d,k: d.setdefault(k, {}), 'bc', D)['d'] = [2,3,4]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы у вас была конструкция такого вида:

```
D = {
    'b': {
        'c': {
            'd': []
        }
    }
}
```

То ваш код `D['b']['c']['d'] = [2], [3], [4]` бы сработал, а именно создал бы кортеж во втором вложенном словаре по ключу `d`, вот такого вида:

```
([2], [3], [4])
```

В Python конечно есть возможность кратко присваивать значения переменным:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

И даже делать различного рода финты с помощью этой возможности например поменять местами значения переменных:

```
a = 1
b = 2

a, b = b, a
```

Но в вашем случае вы обращались ко второму вложенному словарю к элементу с ключом `d` которого у вас прост не было.

Comment: Не хватает примера, как всё-таки сделать то что нужно автору. )

Comment: Но зато хорошо объяснили, что сейчас происходит.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin MaxU дал уже пример, я просто описал в чем причина ошибки, вдруг будет полезно )

Comment: D['b'] = 3 - это работает

Answer (score 3):

В английской версии SO - [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Python 3:

```
In [158]: D
Out[158]: {'a': 1, 'z': 100}

In [159]: D = {**D, **dict(zip(['b','c','d'], [2,3,4]))}

In [160]: D
Out[160]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'z': 100}
```

или

```
In [164]: D['e'], D['f'], D['g'] = 5,6,7

In [165]: D
Out[165]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'z': 100}
```

Comment: а інших методів додаваннянових елементів в словник масово є, що б не по одному(щось схоже на x, y, z = 1, 2, 3)?

Comment: Дякую за силку, знавби гарно англійську скориставсяби цією силкою

Comment: @Pero, додав у відповідь...

Comment: `D = {**D, **dict(zip(['b','c','d'], [2,3,4]))}` — особая питоновая магия. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, к сожалению, работает только в третьем питоне...

Comment: @Pero объяснение: [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044) Если вы хотите по пути объединения словарей пойти: [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно сделать в одну строку:

```
 D.update({'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd':[4]})
```

Или по одному элементу:

```
D['b']= [2]
D['c']= [3]
D['d']= [4]
```