# Не могу вернуть значение из метода

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день. Написал код, но в нем что-то не так. Предполагалось, что при вызове метода get_videos_from_links в переменную results будет передаваться словарь из метода get_videos_from_watch. Переменные в нем находятся верно. но обратно не передаются... В чем проблема? Спасибо

```html
def get_videos_from_watch(watch_link):
    r = requests.get(watch_link)
    watch_links = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=([^\'\"]+)', watch_link)
    short_links = ['https://youtu.be/' + x for x in watch_links]
    print('ссылка:', short_links)
    author_find_result = (re.findall(r'(author":"[^\"]+)', r.text))
    author = author_find_result[0][9:]
    print('автор:', author)
    description_find_result = (re.findall(r'("title":"[^\"]+)', r.text))
    description = description_find_result[0][9:]
    print('описание:', description)
    print('Парсинг ссылки с watch', short_links)
    return {'watch_links': watch_links, 'short_link': short_links, 'author': author, 'description': description}

def get_videos_from_links(attachments):
    result = {}
    if '/embed/' in attachments:
        result += get_videos_from_embed(attachments)
    elif '/user/' in attachments:
        result += get_videos_from_channel(attachments)
    elif '/channel/' in attachments:
        result += get_videos_from_channel(attachments)
    elif '/watch?v=' in attachments:
        result += get_videos_from_watch(attachments)
    else:
        result += get_videos_from_channel(attachments)
```

Comment: Не помню, чтобы в Python словари можно было складывать. У вас должно вылетать исключение `TypeError`.

Comment: что значит "обратно не передаются"? Как вы об этом узнаёте? Приведите traceback

Comment: связанный вопрос [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, о каких двух словарях идет речь. Словарь должен быть один.                                                                          
Вот TypeError:                                                                                   
 result += get_videos_from_watch(attachments)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: @ЕвгенийАлександрович нажмите на ссылку выше, где подробно описано почему нельзя dict + dict в Питоне написать (и соответственно почему dict += dict не работает)

Comment: Все, я, вроде разобрался, спасибо