# Почему слишком много значений?

Tags: python, массивы, python-2.x, python-2.7

В скрипте из файла я получаю текст в виде `0=1000;4=2000;6=1500`. Я разделяю его по тэгам `;` и `=` и на выходе у меня получается массив:

`[['0', '1000'], ['4', '2000'], ['6', '1500']]`

И мне из этого массива нужно 0, 4 и 6 перенести в массив `keys`, а 1000, 2000 и 1500 в массив `power` ПО ПОРЯДКУ, причем если в массиве `keys` уже есть 0, 4 или 6, то заменить в массиве `power` текущее значение на новое, а в `keys` ничего не менять.

Я пытаюсь делать это так:

```
for k,v in enumerate(m[0]):
for kk,vv in enumerate(net):
    for kkk,vvv in enumerate(v):
        if int(vv[0]) == vvv:
            try:
                power[keys.index(vv[0])] = int(vv[1])
            except:
                keys.append(int(vv[0]))
                power.append(int(vv[1]))
```

Но в вместо того, чтобы в массивах `keys` и `power` было по 3 значения, эти 3 значения повторяются 9 раз.

Вот содержимое `m[0]`:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

И содержимое `net`:

```
[['0', '1000'], ['4', '2000'], ['6', '1500']]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в массивах `keys` и `power` было только по 3 значения из массива `net`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше вместо массивов воспользоваться словарем - тогда перезаписывание ключей новыми значениями вы получите "из коробки":

```
import re

s = '0=1000;4=2000;6=1500'

res = dict(re.findall(r'([^;=]*)=([^;=]*)', s))
```

результат:

```
In [19]: print(res)
{'0': '1000', '4': '2000', '6': '1500'}

In [20]: print(res.keys())
dict_keys(['0', '4', '6'])

In [21]: print(res.values())
dict_values(['1000', '2000', '1500'])
```

---

парсинг повторяющихся ключей в одной строке:

```
In [26]: s = '0=1000;4=2000;6=1500;0=777;6=1111'

In [27]: res = dict(re.findall(r'([^;=]*)=([^;=]*)', s))

In [28]: res
Out[28]: {'0': '777', '4': '2000', '6': '1111'}
```

парсинг повторяющихся ключей в нескольких строках:

```
In [29]: s1 = '0=1000;4=2000;6=1500'

In [30]: s2 = '0=000;4=444;6=666'
```

1. если все строки можно обработать сразу:

   ```
   In [31]: res = dict(re.findall(r'([^;=]*)=([^;=]*)', ';'.join([s1, s2])))

   In [32]: res
   Out[32]: {'0': '000', '4': '444', '6': '666'}
   ```
2. если строки нужно обработать последовательно:

   ```
   In [38]: res = dict(re.findall(r'([^;=]*)=([^;=]*)', s1))

   In [39]: res.update(dict(re.findall(r'([^;=]*)=([^;=]*)', s2)))

   In [40]: res
   Out[40]: {'0': '000', '4': '444', '6': '666'}
   ```

---

> Мне нужно получать ключ словаря по его значению. Но как это сделать?
>   Или делать второй словарь?

Для этого можно создать "реверсированный" словарь, но учтите, что по определению у словаря ключи должны быть уникальными:

```
n [59]: d = dict(a=1,b=2,c=1,d=4)

n [60]: d
ut[60]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 4}

n [61]: d_rev = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}
```

т.к. значение `1` встречается больше одного раза, то в реверсированном словаре - ключ `1` будет содержать только одно значение:

```
n [62]: d_rev
ut[62]: {1: 'c', 2: 'b', 4: 'd'}

In [64]: d_rev[1]
Out[64]: 'c'

In [65]: d_rev[2]
Out[65]: 'b'

In [66]: d_rev[4]
Out[66]: 'd'
```

Comment: То есть не нужно проверять наличие значения, а сразу записывать?

Comment: @6o6ep, это зависит от того одну строку вы обрабатываете или несколько... Для обработки нескольких строк вам может понадобиться [объединение словарей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: @6o6ep о [сложении словарей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044)