# Составной словарь в Python с несколькими значениями из других словарей по идентичному ключу

Tags: python, словари

Сразу оговорюсь – я не программист, а изучаю Python для собственных конкретных целей (обработка данных, полученных из сети), поэтому если мой вопрос покажется наивным и простым – прошу не пенять.

Итак, есть три разных словаря с идентичными ключами. Значения – разные, но могут совпадать как в пределах одного словаря, так и в разных словарях.
Например (значения сделал в виде списка, поскольку понимаю, что по-другому добавлять значения к одному ключу не выйдет):

```
dict_1={'a': [2],
    'b': [8],
    'c': [6],
    'd': [2]}

dict_2={'a': [2],
    'b': [7],
    'c': [7],
    'd': [3]}

dict_3={'a': [3],
    'b': [6],
    'c': [8],
    'd': [3]}
```

Задача: получить новый словарь (либо с нуля, либо на основе одного из указанных – совершенно не важно) в котором каждый ключ получит значения от всех трёх словарей:

```
dict_all={'a': [2, 2, 3],
      'b': [8, 7, 6],
      'c': [6, 7, 8],
      'd': [2, 3, 3]}
```

Comment: @Anton, спасибо, исправлены.

Comment: [`sum_dicts()`](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/3502)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd    # pip install pandas

res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]]).to_dict('list')
```

результат:

```
{'a': [2, 2, 3], 'b': [8, 7, 6], 'c': [6, 7, 8], 'd': [2, 3, 3]}
```

в виде Pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [7]: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3]])
Out[7]:
   a  b  c  d
0  2  8  6  2
0  2  7  7  3
0  3  6  8  3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import copy

dict_all = copy.deepcopy(dict_1)

for loop_dict in dict_2, dict_3:
    for k, v in loop_dict.items():
        try:
            dict_all[k].extend(v)
        except KeyError:
            dict_all[k] = v
```

Если сохранность в исходном виде `dict_1` не нужна, можно обойтись без его глубокого копирования. Перехват ислкючения нужен на случай, если в `dict_1` нет каких-либо ключей, встречающихся в других словарях.

Answer (score 3):

```
dict_all = {}

for key in dict_1:
    dict_all[key] = [d[key][0] for d in (dict_1, dict_2, dict_3)]
```

*Примечание:*

Исходные словари *не нужны иметь в качестве значений списки* - в том случае просто удалите в моем решении `[0]` (служащего для выбора первого - единого - элемента исходных списков).

Answer (score 2):

Оптимально не привязывать необходимый набор ключей к какому-либо "рабочему" словарю, в следующей функции набор ключей вынесен в качестве параметра.

В ваших словарях значения представлены списками с одним элементом, удобно привести их к общему базовому виду с помощью отдельной функции-фильтра

```
def general_dict(key_list, ad, bd, cd):
    result = {}
    for key in key_list:
        t = []
        for d in [ad, bd, cd]:
            try:
                t.append(d[key])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        result[key] = t
    return result


def dict_filter(dict):
    y = {}
    for x in dict:
        y[x] = dict[x][0]
    return y

dict_1={'a': [2],
    'b': [8],
    'c': [6],
    'd': [2]}

dict_2={'a': [2],
    'b': [7],
    'c': [7],
    'd': [3]}

dict_3={'a': [3],
    'b': [6],
    'c': [8],
    'd': [3]}

print dict_filter(dict_1)
# {'a': 2, 'c': 6, 'b': 8, 'd': 2}
print general_dict(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dict_filter(dict_1), dict_filter(dict_2), dict_filter(dict_3))
# {'a': [2, 2, 3], 'c': [6, 7, 8], 'b': [8, 7, 6], 'd': [2, 3, 3]}
```