# Как объединить 2 словаря одним выражением?

Tags: python, алгоритм, словари, структуры-данных

Каким образом можно объединить 2 словаря одним выражением?

Метод `update()` я бы использовать не хотел, так как он изменяет содержимое словаря, а не создаёт новый объект.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431760)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Для Python 3.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/5741205) можно объединить два и более словарей следующим способом:

создаем словари:

```
In [1]: a = dict(a=1, b=2)

In [2]: b = dict(c=3, d=4, a=100)
```

получилось:

```
In [3]: a
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [4]: b
Out[4]: {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'a': 100}
```

объединяем:

```
In [5]: res = {**a, **b}
```

результат:

```
In [6]: res
Out[6]: {'a': 100, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

---

для Python 2.7 - решение предложенное [@extrn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324712/extrn) в комментарии:

```
print dict({1: 2}, **{3: 4})     # в 3.x так нельзя
>>> {1: 2, 3: 4}

print dict({'1': 2}, **{'3': 4}) # но так - можно
>>> {'1': 2, '3': 4}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю что можно через команду union .

Вот пример

songs1 = {'Три белых коня', 'Happy new year', 'Снежинка'}

songs2 = {'Last christmas', 'Снежинка', 'Happy new year'}

print(songs1.union(songs2))

{'Три белых коня', 'Снежинка', 'Last christmas', 'Happy new year'}

Comment: Отформатируйте код. Это не словари