# При сложении словарей выводится None

Tags: python, функции, словарь

Объясните тупому человек, как это работает. Почему выводится None. И почему если в print сразу вывести, то выводится. Важно понимание, как работает это, и как же все таки передать в функцию словарь и вывести его?

```
def summ(arg1,arg2):
  print(arg1.update(arg2)) # выводит None

a = {'a':500, 'b':5874, 'c': 560,'d':400, 'e':5874, 'f': 20}
b = {'g':40, 'm':574, 'h': 760,'p':440}
summ(a,b)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def summ(arg1,arg2):
  res = arg1.update(arg2)
  return(res) 

a = {'a':500, 'b':5874, 'c': 560,'d':400, 'e':5874, 'f': 20}
b = {'g':40, 'm':574, 'h': 760,'p':440}

print(summ(a,b)) # тоже выводит None
print(a.update(b)) # выводит словарь в котором все сложилось КААААААК?
```

Comment: Метод update модифицирует первый словарь и ничего не возвращает. Нужно делать отдельно `a.update(b)`, потом отдельно `print(a)`

Comment: Связанный вопрос (там можно посмотреть способы объединения словарей): [Почему нельзя просто взять и сложить два словаря?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь `dict` в Python является mutable (изменяемой) структурой данных (в отличие от `tuple`, например) - т.е. возможно изменять экземпляр класса (`a` и `b` у Вас). Поэтому функция `update` класса `dict` **изменяет сам экземпляр**, из которого она вызвана (`arg1` в вашем случае), а не возвращает новый экземпляр словаря (`update()` вообще ничего не возвращает - отсюда и выводится `None`).

Из сказанного следует, что Вам следует из функции `summ` возвращать либо `arg1`, после добавления к нему `arg2` (но при этом изменится словарь `a`, т.к. `arg1` по факту это тот же самый словарь `a`, т.к. аргументы передаются по ссылкам),

```py
def summ(arg1, arg2):
    arg1.update(arg2)
    return arg1
```

либо использовать код ниже (в этом случае словари `d1` и `d2` не изменятся, а функция вернёт **новый экземпляр** класса `dict`):

```py
def sumDicts(d1: dict, d2: dict) -> dict:
    d = d1.copy()
    d.update(d2)
    return d


def main():
    a = {'a': 500, 'b': 5874, 'c': 560, 'd': 400, 'e': 5874, 'f': 20}
    b = {'g': 40, 'm': 574, 'h': 760, 'p': 440}

    print(sumDicts(a, b))
    # Или то же самое..
    c = sumDicts(a, b)
    print(c)

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Подобный код успешно складывает словари.

**P.S.**

Ваш код у меня ничего, кроме `None`, не вывел.

Подробнее про изменяемые и неизменяемые структуры данных см. документацию Python и https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747